# @font-face rendering in Chrome (Android/Win7)

Tags: google-chrome, rendering, font-face, chrome-for-android

With the site I'm working on, I'm having two problems with @font-face rendering - both with Chrome for Android (tested on Samsung Galaxy S) and with Chrome for Win7. Both latest versions.

The issues are slightly different visually, but I think are related to the same thing.

Here's few screenshots to better introduce you what I'm talking about

[image: Android - proper]

> Chrome (user agent) for iPhone/Android - OK

[image]

> Chrome for Android - WRONG

[image]

> Chrome for Ubuntu - OK

[image]

> Chrome for Win7 - WRONG

So, as you can see, font in Chrome for Android is not rendered proper - it displays some default font and not the one we're using (farnhamdisplay). On the other side, it works good in Chrome user agent and in Chrome for iPhone.

Second issue...same font...it's cut on the top, only in Chrome for Windows 7. On the other side, works fine with Chrome for Ubuntu.

This also works proper in any other browsers (Firefox, IE, ...)

Here's also an example of CSS code for that (for mobile version):

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Farnhamdisplay-regular';
    src: url('../fonts/farnhamdisplay-regular.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/farnhamdisplay-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../fonts/farnhamdisplay-regular.svg#proxima_nova_ltregular') format('svg')
        url('../fonts/farnhamdisplay-regular.woff') format('woff'),
        url('../fonts/farnhamdisplay-regular.ttf') format('truetype');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
}

#navigation {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    padding-left:48px;
    font:27px/29px "Farnhamdisplay-regular";
    text-transform:uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin:18px 0 0 31px;
    color:#333;
    letter-spacing:2px;
}
```

Anyone got any ideas for this? I've stumbled upon few similar issues and as far as I understand it's probably problem on the Chrome side. It works for example with Google fonts but it's not working with some custom TypeKit fonts etc.

Comment: Are the mime-types on your server correct? I have had issues with IIS on woff files ect.

Comment: Think this is not an issue. Right now, I've also noticed that in mobile version, font is properly displayed in horizontal mode and it's wrong in vertical mode.

Comment: Ok, so I've fixed mobile version - it was some kind of problem with container (where the font was) height, really weird.